# How to get intersection of 2 sets in redis?

Tags: redis, geolocation

I have 2 sets in Redis, one is made by hmset:

```
HMSET cars:1 make Ferrari model 458 color red topSpeed 202mph
```

then:

```
SADD make:Ferrari 1
```

and when I enter this command:

```
SMEMBERS make:Ferrari
```

I get "1"
then I add:`geoadd carLoc 13.361389 38.115556 1`

I am trying to get intersection of these 2 sets, with this command: `georadius carLoc 13.361389 38.115556 1 store key1` 
I filter the first set and store in another set but I can't find a way to store the result of `SMEMBERS make:Ferrari` to another set and get intersection of them. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is that you want to find the intersection of a set and a zset, then there is no native way of doing this. You have two options that I can tell:

1. Convert `make:Ferrari` to a zset, choosing some arbitrary weights
2. Create a lua script to do this programmatically

In general, #1 would be easier to do if it is at all possible to convert that key to a zset. If it's not easy to do, then consider creating two keys: one is a set `make:Ferrari`, and another is a zset `z:make:Ferrari` and use the second for the intersection.

Comment: Actually, you *can* intersect a Zset and a Set natively - the OP was asking aboud intersecting a Hash with a Set, which is not possible.\